# Bootstrap 4 modal disappears and leaves backdrop on Ajax Refesh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a Rails 5.1 application with bootstrap alpha 4-v6 and I'm launching a modal like so:

**_assigned.html.erb** (Excerpt)

```
<%= link_to "Notes", '#note-modal', data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#note-modal#{index}", backdrop: false }, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary' %>
<%= render 'shared/note_modal', call: call, index: index %>
```

Here is the content of my `note-modal`

**_note_modal.html.erb**

```
<div id="note-modal<%= index %>" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Call Notes <%= call.incident_number %></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_for @call_note, url: call_notes_path, method: 'post', html: {class: "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :call_id, value: call.id %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
          <%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x12" %>
          <%= f.button "Create", class: 'btn btn-info btn-sm' %>
        <% end %>

        <% call.call_notes.each do |cn| %>
          <li><%= cn.body %> | <%= cn.user.username %> | <%= cn.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M") %></li>
        <% end %>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I'm in the view and trigger the modal it will pop up and work, but I have an ajax call in my main view that refreshes the view partials and when it does the modal disappears but the backdrop remains and you cannot click anywhere to make it disappear.  You have to refresh the browser window to get rid of the backdrop.

I've been reading the bootstrap 4 docs and googling but have not found an answer so far.  Was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

It should be noted that this behavior happens on the latest version of chrome as well as Safari.

Is this a bug, or is my code not setup right?

By the way inside of my view here is the JS that gets fired to make an ajax refresh of the URL and partials endpoint:

**wheelchair_calls.html.erb**

```
<div id="active">
  <%= render "assigned" %>
</div>

<div id="inactive">
  <%= render "unassigned" %>
</div>


<script>
  $(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
      $.getScript('/calls/wheelchair_calls/?region=<%= params[:region] %>')
    }, 15000);
  });
</script>
```

Here is the js that gets fired:

**wheelchair_calls.js.erb**

```
$("#active").html("<%= escape_javascript render("assigned") %>");
$("#inactive").html("<%= escape_javascript render("unassigned") %>");
```

Comment: So every 15 seconds it loads and executes a script from `wheelchair_calls/`? What is in that script? What does the HTML look like? What happens when you run `$.getScript` manually from the console? What happens when you execute each line of that script manually from the console one at a time?

Comment: I'll add it to my original content, one moment.

Comment: Try adding a listener on the modals to see if they are fired. `$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  console.log('hidding modal'); 
  console.log(e);
})`

Answer (score 1):

Oh I know why. Your modals are in `_assigned.html.erb`, which is inside `#active`. When you execute the 15s script with

```
$("#active").html("<%= escape_javascript render("assigned") %>");
```

you are detaching the modal `<div>`s from the browser document object model (DOM) and discarding them, then re-rendering new modals with the same name. This makes the modals disappear.

This deletes the modal that has popped up. The backdrop is something separate that Bootstrap overlays, probably attached to `<body>`.

You have to keep your modals static on the page, and only re-render/refresh the absolute minimum HTML. If you need to refresh data inside the modal, you have to make a separate `<div>` for that and only refresh that `<div>` inside the `.modal-body`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information, How would this work in rails.  Would I have to keep the modal as part of the _assigned.html.erb partial so that it refreshes?  I'm not sure what you mean by keeping it static.  I'll tinker around but if you could elaborate a bit that'd be great :)

Comment: It depends on what you are refreshing and why you are refreshing. Just refresh the absolute minimum bit of HTML, and make sure it doesn't include the `<div class="modal">`. You will probably have to refactor, and refresh many little bits, instead of a giant single bit.

Comment: The problem is I need all the HTML to refresh, that's the point of refreshing the partials.  I need every bit of html/data to refresh.  Not just small pieces, I need to poll the whole partial every 15 seconds.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this answer. Figured this was the case but only made sense to me after reading it from another perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine that this was a bug with bootstrap 4, leaving the backdrop after the ajax refreshes the views.  This is the new modal code:

```
<div id="assigned-note-modal<%= index %>" class="modal hide fade" data-backdrop="">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Call Notes <%= call.incident_number %></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= form_for @call_note, url: call_notes_path, method: 'post' do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :call_id, value: call.id %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
          <%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x12" %>
          <%= f.button "Create", class: 'btn btn-info btn-sm' %>
        <% end %>

        <% call.call_notes.each do |cn| %>
          <li><%= cn.body %> | <%= cn.user.username %> | <%= cn.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y-%H:%M") %></li>
        <% end %>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By using `data-backdrop=""` the backdrop does not persist after the modal closes.

Comment: It's not a bug. You are explicitly deleting the modal when you call [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2). "When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content. Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content." You can't expect Bootstrap to recover when you are deleting elements it is managing.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I'll look into this further.  For now the backdrop issue is simply an annoyance.  It's really not part of the core functionality that I'm extremely worried about.  I will revisit this later.  Appreciate your help!.